# Javascript recursively count

Tags: javascript, object, recursion

I applied for a job where I was given this task. I had to write a function `reversePrint()` which returns a reversed array with values from a passed object.

Here is the object

```
var someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
};
```

My attempt

```
function reversePrint(linkedList) {
  // empty array with the result
  var b = [];
  // while loop to check if current next is not null
  while ( linkedList.next !== null ) {
    // push current value into the array
    b.push(linkedList.value);
    // go one level deeper
    linkedList = linkedList.next;
  }
  // push the last value into the array
  b.push(linkedList.value);
  // return reversed array
  return b.reverse();
}
```

The function works, but I have a feeling that there is a better way to do this. I have already searched stackoverflow for javascript recursive operations, but could not find anything that would be considered a duplicate. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Since you have a working example, and you are looking to optimise it the code, would it be more suitable for the question to be asked over at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: That seems just fine. It can be more concise, but "more concise" does not necessarily mean "better" (and frequently doesn't, such as when it's harder to understand). Your approach is simple, doesn't do a lot of unnecessary work. Other than perhaps not using `!== null` (just `if (linkedList.next)` is fine) and possibly using a variable instead of assigning back to the `linkedList` parameter itself, I'd be happy with it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder when I mentioned better I did not mean more concise, but perhaps performance wise this could be improved

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Well, it's a matter of opinion, and you're right, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with the OP's code, but  a recursive solution would seem to match the recursive nature of the data structure better, and it also can be written to avoid the `reverse`. Avoiding `reverse` with the iterative solution is possible, of course, but it requires an expensive `unshift` onto the front of the array. On the other hand, the recursive solution yielding the reversed array is not tail-optimizable and might be best avoided if the input could be very deep.

Comment: @torazaburo: Yeah, with the reverse bit, building the array on exiting a recursive call series would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your code, but your instinct is right: a recursive solution would seem to match the recursive nature of the data structure better, would be more concise, and also can be written to avoid the reverse.

```js
var someList = {value: 1, next: {
    value: 2, next: {
        value: 3, next: {
            value: 4, next: null}}}};

function reversePrint(input) {
  return !input ? [] : reversePrint(input.next).concat(input.value); 
}

console.log(reversePrint(someList));
```

Note that this solution is not tail-optimizable and might be best avoided if the input could be very deep. A tail-optimizable solution would be:

```
function reversePrint(input) {
  return function inner(input) {
    return !input ? [] : [input.value].concat(inner(input.next));
  }(input).reverse();
}
```

Avoiding reverse with the iterative solution is possible, of course, but it requires an expensive unshift onto the front of the array at each step. On the other hand, the recursive solutions create multiple arrays of gradually increasing length, which is not exactly cheap either.

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/zwzecvqf/2/

Here you have a recursive function.

```
function reversePrint (item) {
  var nextItem = item.next
  var items

  if (nextItem) {
        items = reversePrint(nextItem)
  } else {
        items = [];
  }  

  items.push(item.value)
  return  items
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using recursion you can also do it like this.

```js
var someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
  
};

function reversePrint(linkedList) {
  var r = []
  if(linkedList.next) r = r.concat(reversePrint(linkedList.next))
  r.push(linkedList.value)
  return r
}

console.log(reversePrint(someList))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another recursive solution, but avoiding creating and throwing away multiple intermediary arrays:

```
function reversePrint(node, array) {
  // Fill in the array if not given
  array = array || [];
  // Recurse if appropriate
  if (node.next) {
    reversePrint(node.next, array);
  }
  // Add the value on the way out
  array.push(node.value);
  return array;
}
```

```js
function reversePrint(node, array) {
  array = array || [];
  if (node.next) {
    reversePrint(node.next, array);
  }
  array.push(node.value);
  return array;
}
var someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
};
console.log(reversePrint(someList));
```

Comment: wouldnt removing array=array||[] and return Array make it faster ( the recursive)?

Comment: if you start it like this: var solution=[]; reversePrint(someList,solution); alert(solution); it should work in my opinion

Comment: @Jonasw: Yes, that would work *if* `reversePrint` is a closure over the context containing `solution`. No, it wouldn't be faster in any real-world way.

Answer (score 0):

What about not using recursion? I didn't find information this is not banned.

```
var someList = {
    value: 1,
    next: {
        value: 2,
        next: {
            value: 3,
            next: {
                value: 4,
                next: null
            }
        }
    }
};

function reversePrint()
{
    var currentNode = someList;
    var cacheList = [];
    do
    {
        cacheList.push(currentNode.value);
        currentNode = currentNode.next;
    }
    while(currentNode != null);

    cacheList.reverse();  
    return cacheList;
}

var reverseList = reversePrint(); // [4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: More or less. I avoided nasty `// push the last value into the array` using `do ... while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here using a recursive function to sub objects values

```
function reversePrint(linkedList) {
  // empty array with the result
  var b = [];

  function addValues(subList){
     if(linkedList.next)
        addValues(linkedList.next);

    b.push(item.value);
  }

  addValues(linkedList);
  return b.revers();  
}
```

Comment: Can you write this so it creates the reversed array to start with?